# "Riposare" vs "riposarsi" (= to take a break)

Tags: word-meaning, verbs, difference, synonym

Is there any difference between "riposare" and "riposarsi" when they mean "to take a break" ? Example:

- We work during the day and we rest/take a break at night.
- Lavoriamo di giorno e (ci) riposiamo di notte.

Comment: The form with “ci” is more colloquial.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your sentence, both are synonyms, but, according to [Treccani dictionary](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/riposare) the version with pronoun is more commonly used:

> Cessare, smettere momentaneamente un’attività, e quindi sostare, prendere tregua per sollievo e ristoro fisico e psichico: *gli altri dì non credere che noi riposiamo* (Boccaccio); più comunem., con la particella pron., *riposarsi*: *Quante ’l villan ch’al poggio si riposa, ... Vede lucciole giù per la vallea ...* (Dante); *riposarsi da un lavoro, da un viaggio; riposarsi un istante, un’ora; dopo cena mi riposo un po’ e poi mi rimetto a studiare*;

Treccani dictionary states that the version without the pronoun is usually used when when you want to indicate that the rest is prolonged for a certain time, in sleep or lying down:

> La forma senza la particella pron. s’incontra di preferenza quando si vuole indicare che il riposo si prolunga per un certo tempo, nel sonno o comunque stando distesi: *sta riposando sul divano, sulla poltrona, sul prato*;

Answer (score 2):

Riposarsi is a reflexive verb.

The reflexive verbs are used when the subject is also the object of the action.

Mi lavo = I wash myself

Si veste = She dresses herself

You can say that a verb is reflexive if you see a reflexive pronoun (mi, ti, ci, vi, si)

When you use imperative or indefinite (infinitive, participle, gerund) you must attach the reflexive pronoum as suffix:

Lavati = lava + ti = go wash yourself (imperative)

Vai a lavarti i denti = lavare + ti = go brush your teeth (infinitive)

Since the action of “resting” cannot be applied to any other individual, you may use “riposare” and “riposarsi” with the same meaning.

Source: I’m italian.

Comment: Benvenuto su Italian.SE!

Comment: Isn't "riposarsi" a pronominal verb? There is no reflexive action in it.

Comment: @AlanEvangelista It's kind of an annoying choice of terminology  but in Italian *pronominal verbs* are more commonly known as *reflexive verbs* (as we were bemoaning on another question, really  they should be called *verbs in the mediopassive voice*, but that ship has sailed centuries ago).

Comment: @Denis Nardin That is confusing indeed. Thanks for making it clear.